# Azure Devops keeps asking me to re-authenticate

Tags: azure-devops

When I am working in Azure DevOps on a regular basis this popup appears.
I reauthenticate but then it will just appear again.

I have tried logging out, clearing cookies, using another browser but with no luck.
Some days it works but most days I get this message at least a dozen times and right now I cannot get rid of it.

I use a work account to log in and it started happening when I changed the email address domain on this account (not sure if that is related). This was about a year ago and I have even changed computers since then.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is a little bit different than when I came across the same error message, but these are the steps that I used when one of our staff members ran into this issue, using Microsoft Edge.  The following assumes you are using the Desktop version of Azure Test runner as well.

1. Save and close Test runner (may have to use Task manager if not able to close normally)
2. Open Microsoft Edge and go to the Settings area > Cookies and site permissions > Pop-ups and redirects
3. Uncheck the first box to allow popups, as there are a few sites that use this when using test runner
4. Run the Test runner desktop application from Azure DevOps again, and make sure to sign into both the Desktop app and the pop-up in MS Edge to authenticate
5. Test and save